# Xcode giving error - "Failed to create provisioning profile."

Tags: ios, xcode

I was trying to create my first Xcode Project but throws error - "Failed to create provisioning profile." Please Suggest. Thanks

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The error message is clear enough. Have you registered devices under your Apple developer id?

Comment: Are you the admin of your developer portal? Maybe you need more rights to create the profile. In the meantime you can develop using a simulator or your personal Developer Account

Comment: No not yet , as now i was just running on simulator.

Comment: Ok . So this is only provisioning issues?